# iMessage truncating messaging history

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

A coworker of mine has recently noticed that for any person with whom he has a long SMS history, and with whom iMessage routing has started, the messaging logs with that person are now being truncated. He can only hit the "load more messages" button five times before  it hits the apparent end of the logs. Is anyone else noticing this? No one with whom I share that much history has upgraded to iMessage yet.

I'm a bit worried, because my girlfriend will be upgrading to iOS 5 soon, but we both like the fact that we can scroll all the way back to before we were dating, and sometimes do so just to laugh at the random conversations we've had. We're talking about thousands of texts over two years, and I really hope the default isn't to clear that.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to iOS 5, I used [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) for this. You can also try [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/).

They probably still work, I just haven't tried recently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any solution for you except to take screenshots of your older conversations and put them in an album in your photos app. Do this by pressing the home and sleep button simultaneously (this will capture what is currently on your screen), then they will be on your photos app. To make a new album, go to albums in the photos app, then tap "Edit" in the top right corner, and subsequently tap "New Album" in the top left corner, and put all the photos in it that you'd like. Good Luck!

Comment: That's not a bad idea, except for the fact that we're talking about thousands of messages. For now, I've just taken regular backups of my smsdb file, and have a copy of hers as well. My coworker tore his smsdb apart and it seems to contain the excluded texts; the app just won't allow you to view them anymore.